# In Blazor, how can I rerender the same instance of a component multiple times?

Tags: c#, blazor

In Blazor, suppose I have some column headings, and I want to repeat them several times in the DOM, such on every one of 10 tables. Is there a way to have one instance of a component render in multiple places (with the identical content and behavior, of course)?  I'm imagining something like this minimal example, though obviously this isn't it:

```
<table>
   <ColumnHeadings @ref="MainHeadings">
   <tr>...</tr>
</table>
...
<table>
   @RenderComponent(MainHeadings)
   <tr>...</tr>
</table>
<table>
   @RenderComponent(MainHeadings)
   <tr>...</tr>
</table>

...
```

Comment: Given the performance comments in regards to using too many components in this article, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0, you may want to consider a different approach. Perhaps a MarkupString representing your object could do you well.

Comment: Great idea, but is there a way to set a MarkupString from a component instance?  I have dynamic pieces in this component.

Comment: How much of a performance gain do you expect?  I'd expect it to be negligible.

Comment: No idea till I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to keep behaviors, my comment about using a MarkupString is probably not the best alternative for you. JSInterop could come to the rescue, but at what cost? If multiplying the number of component isn't a performance deal breaker, this should work

```
<ColumnHeadings @ref="MainHeadings" />
<tr>...</tr>
<ColumnHeadings @ref="MainHeadings" />
<tr>...</tr>
<ColumnHeadings @ref="MainHeadings" />
```

Maybe just a "frozen" row at the top of your grid?

Comment: I simplified my question to avoid confusion, but I actually want to have many different tables with one headings row for each, not one table.  I think your code would result in three different instances, not one.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way in which true [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) can be implemented in Blazor.

A simple foreach loop for column model can work here.

```
public class ColumnModel
{
  public Title {get; set;}
}
```

HeaderCell.razor

```
    <div>
       @Model.Title
    </div>

@code
{
   [Parameter]
   public ColumnModel Model {get; set;}
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to implement it as a RenderFragment:

RenderFragmentCollections.razor

```
public static RenderFragment<ColumnModel> HeaderCell = model => 

@<div>
   @Model.Title
</div>;
```

Table.razor

// Component approach

```
<tr>
@foreach(var model in ColumnModels)
{
<td>
   <HeaderCell Model="model"/>
</td>
}
</tr>
```

//RenderFragmentApproach

```
<tr>
@foreach(var model in ColumnModels)
{
 <td>
   @RenderFragmentCollections.HeaderCell(model)
 </td>
}
</tr>
```

RenderFragment approach has better performance. *However* you cannot add events to it. So if your table headers need click events for sorting etc, you will have to add those at the  level.

Of course, you can improve the performance further by using a Header component that accepts a collection of ColumnModel s and renders all of them inside a single component.

P.S. If you are trying to achieve exactly what you have described, I think it can be solved better using CSS position:sticky and allowing rows overflow. You don't need to render the header after every x rows.

Comment: I simplified my question to avoid confusion, but I actually want to have many different tables with one headings row for each, not one table.  I've modified my question to reflect that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Specifically, do you want to have common behaviour or shared state? If former, simply use the component. If latter, use the same *model* like in MVVM model. 
If it is for performance, I don't think repeating 10s of components on a page has serious penalty. Microsoft docs specifically mention that performance considerations kick in only after you have hundreds of components.

Comment: "Why do you want to do that?" I suspect that I have performance problems and too much need to rerender due to thousands of components on the page.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/performance?view=aspnetcore-7.0#avoid-thousands-of-component-instances

Comment: Would it be correct to assume that you have thousands of tables with exactly the same header content in each? Then I suggest you use Blazor virtualization: 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

> Note Renderfragment format updated per comments.

You can use a `RenderFragment`.  Here's a demo using the standard WeatherForecast page.  This is Net8, but it's the same for all previous versions.  It goes over the top with `RenderFragments` to demonstrate their use.

```cs
@page "/weather"

<PageTitle>Weather</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates showing data.</p>

@if (forecasts == null)
{
    @_loading
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        @_header
        @foreach (var forecast in forecasts!)
        {
            @_row(forecast)
        }
    </table>
}

@code {
    private RenderFragment _loading =>
    @<p><em>Loading...</em></p>;

    private RenderFragment _header =>
    @<tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Temp. (C)</th>
        <th>Temp. (F)</th>
        <th>Summary</th>
    </tr>;

    private RenderFragment<WeatherForecast> _row => forecast => __builder =>
    {
        @if (_counter > 9)
        {
            _counter = 0;
            @_header
        }
        <tr>
            <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
            <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
            <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
        </tr>
        {
            _counter++;
        }
    };

    private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;
    private int _counter;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Simulate asynchronous loading to demonstrate a loading indicator
        await Task.Delay(500);

        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        var summaries = new[] { "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching" };
        forecasts = Enumerable.Range(1, 50).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = summaries[Random.Shared.Next(summaries.Length)]
            }).ToArray();
    }

    private class WeatherForecast
    {
        public DateOnly Date { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureC { get; set; }
        public string? Summary { get; set; }
        public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You can get rid of that __builder : `RenderFragment _loading => @<p><em>Loading...</em></p>;`

Comment: @ℍℍ - true for a one liner.  I was about to ask you are you sure, when I discovered that line breaks after the `@` breaks that approach.  Anyway,  I was trying to demonstrate how to use render fragments. :-)

Comment: I have no problem with multiliners this way. And that __builder is really a 'framework internal' that I'd rather not see.

Comment: You don't need _builder if your RenderFragment is not templated.

Comment: OK gents.  I've added a question on this topic.  Please demonstrate?