# Do I need __builder in a RenderFragment definition

Tags: blazor

In a question ([In Blazor, how can I rerender the same instance of a component multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77475085/in-blazor-how-can-i-rerender-the-same-instance-of-a-component-multiple-times/77476328?noredirect=1#comment136588216_77476328)) it was pointed out that I don't need to use `__builder` in a Blazor defined `RenderFragment`.

Here's an example:

```cs
    private RenderFragment _header => __builder =>
    {
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                <th>Summary</th>
            </tr>
    };
```

Can someone demonstrate how?

Comment: Depends where your method is.  If it's in a razor file then you can do `private RenderFragment _header()
    {
        return @<tr>
                   <th>Date</th>
                   <th>Temp. (C)</th>
                   <th>Temp. (F)</th>
                   <th>Summary</th>
               </tr>;
    }` no problem.

Comment: Agreed and thanks for relying, but that's a method that returns a `RenderFragment`  rather that the assignment of an anonymous method to a `RendeFragment` property.  I asked the question because of comments made in the referred question.

Comment: Then I think the closest you'll get is to discard the `RenderTreeBuilder`?  Like this:

`private RenderFragment header => _ =>
    {
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    };`

Comment: I hadn't though of doing it that way: I knew I wasn't using `__builder`, but just blanked on the discard.    You learn something every day!  Add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The razor compiler will switch rather intelligently with just `@` and `;`.

The following is copy/paste from a working demo:

```
@HelloPlain
@HelloName("Johnny")

@code{    
  
  RenderFragment HelloPlain => @<h3>Hello</h3>;

  RenderFragment HelloName(string name) => @<h3>
        Hello, @name
     </h3>;
}
```

Your sample becomes

```
RenderFragment _header => 
@<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Temp. (C)</th>
    <th>Temp. (F)</th>
    <th>Summary</th>
</tr>;
```

Note that there is a second `=>` here too, hidden in the generated code where it belongs.

Syntax limitation: you cannot put the leading `@` at the end of a line.  So either

```
RenderFragment _header => 
@<tr>
  ...
</tr>
```

or

```
RenderFragment _header => @<tr>
  ...
</tr>
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it that way either.  It's all about what the Razor compiler can interpret.  The only issue with the way you suggest is it's not formatted nicely!

Comment: Yes, you can't have the opening `@` at the end of  a line. A small nuisance.

Comment: You very rarely get everything you want.  Thanks for the answer.  I took my initial solution with `__builder` from the compiled code a long time ago, and then never questioned why I was doing what i was doing.  A classic case of learning a bad habit/pattern.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I can relate, I once ended up coding huge renderfragments manually in code behind, without realizing this was even possible. However when using this approach here, always consider, that perhaps introducing a Component that has a Parameter `RenderFragment<string>` could be much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need lambda argument if it is not a templated component. The following code works (tested, used in prod, uses bootstrap5):

Markups.razor

```
@code
{
    public static RenderFragment LargeProgressSpinner =>
    @<div class="position-absolute top-0 end-0 bottom-0 start-0" style="z-index:1;">
        <div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
            <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-lg fs-1" role="status">
                <span class="visually-hidden">Loading...</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    ;
}
```

Index.razor

```
@Markups.LargeProgressSpinner
```