Does Blazor support passing directly components as generic arguments?
Either I am missing something or this documentation falls short: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/generic-type-support?view=aspnetcore-8.0 All examples are about passing data, while I am interested in passing (directly) a component.
Say I have MyComponent and generic container MyContainer<TComponent>. Within the container .razor page I would like to write:
  @typeparam TComponent where TComponent : ComponentBase
  ...
  <h1>This is my component</h1>
  <TComponent></TComponent>

with such code I am getting error "Found markup element with unexpected name TComponent".
Remark: directly means not using DynamicComponent.

No. Generic typed components don't work this way. Why don't you wanna use <DynamicComponent> ?

@ˈvɔlə Its usage is convoluted. Pity :-). Thank you for the answer.

Yes you can do it, just not writing it in Razor.  See my answer.

You can't do it in Razor, but there's nothing stopping you stepping back and writing it in C#.  That's what the Razor compiler does.
Here's your example with me doing the Razor compiler's job.
    public class GreenOldMan<TComponent> : ComponentBase
        where TComponent : ComponentBase
    {
        protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.AddContent(0, new MarkupString("<h1>This is my component</h1>"));
            builder.OpenComponent<TComponent>(1);
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
    }

It's obviously going to be more complicated than this, but I can only go on what you've shown in the question.
You can also put the code in a RenderFragment in either a C# component class or Razor component:
private RenderFragment MyCode => builder =>
{
    builder.AddContent(0, new MarkupString("<h1>This is my component</h1>"));
    builder.OpenComponent<TComponent>(1);
    builder.CloseComponent();
};

And then use it like this within the markup code:
@MyCode


Thank you very much. This is very interesting approach. Now I have to find a way not to replace entire page with manual rendering but use code and inject it in given place into razor.

See my updated answer on how to do that. Experiment and come back if you have any questions. See https://shauncurtis.github.io/Articles/Blazor-Components.html. The component is the most complex object I've ever met. You won't master it for a long while!  Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77477141/do-i-need-builder-in-a-renderfragment-definition

Many, many thanks for the comment and the links. All this information is very useful!

Since you want to directly pass a component and render it, I suggest you to add a RenderFragment parameter to your component.
FooComponent.razor:
<h1>This is my component</h1>
@ChildContent

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired]
    public required RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
}

You can pass a component to render to this component like this:
<FooComponent>
    <MyCustomComponent />
</FooComponent>

